# TypeORM can find() with relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, typeorm

I am using TypeORM for the first time and unfortunately have to use JavaScript. The docs mostly focus on TypeScript, so I got stuck trying to get an entry with all associated other entries.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "recordings",
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: "uuid",
            primary: true,
            generated: "uuid"
        },
        title: {
            type: "text",
            unique: true,
            nullable: false
        },
        file: {
            type: "text",
            unique: true,
            nullable: false
        }
    },
    relations: {
        recordingAnnotations: {
            target: "recordingAnnotations",
            type: "one-to-many",
            joinTable: true,
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {
    name: "recordingAnnotations",
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: "uuid",
            primary: true,
            generated: "uuid"
        },
        startsAt: {
            type: "int",
            nullable: false
        },
        endsAt: {
            type: "int",
            nullable: false
        },
        content: {
            type: "text",
            unique: true,
            nullable: false
        }
    },
    relations: {
        recording: {
            target: "recordings",
            type: "many-to-one",
            nullable: false,
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        }
    }
};
```

Now I want to find an `recording` entry with all annotations.

```
const repo = conn.getRepository(Recording.name);
const result = await repo.find({
    where: { id },
    relations: [ "recordingAnnotations" ]
});
```

The result I am trying to get would look like the following:

```
    id: "some-uuid",
    title: "Recording 1",
    file: "some-uuid",
    annotations: [
        { id: "some-uuid", startsAt: 0, endsAt: 10, content: "Hello!" },
        { id: "some-uuid", startsAt: 20, endsAt: 25, content: "Bye!" },
    ]
```

The error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property `'joinColumns'` of undefined

Answer (score 1):

In recordings schema, No need to joinTable as it will only works many-to-many relationships,

```
relations: {
    recordingAnnotations: {
        target: "recordingAnnotations",
        type: "one-to-many",
        inverseSide: 'recording'
    }
}
```

We need to specify the inverseSide as `recording`, Because of we have added `recording` relation in `recordingAnnotations` schema and ManyToOne puts the foreign key in the current entity table.

In recordingAnnotations schema,

```
relations: {
    recording: {
        target: "recordings",
        type: "many-to-one",
        nullable: false,
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        joinColumn: true
    }
}
```

We need to specify the joinColumn, Which will add `recordingId`(Foreign Key) in `recordingAnnotations` table.

Addtionally, Here is complete example of using one-to-many relationship: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2503#issuecomment-404834720